# how to upgrade matplotlib version for python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can I upgrade the version of matplotlib to 1.10 for python 2.7

[image]

Comment: you need to upgrade the `six` library, not matplotlib.

Comment: how can I upgrade it ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just installing it again via pip? Example pip command taken from [here:](https://matplotlib.org/2.1.1/users/installing.html)

```
python -mpip install -U matplotlib
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you use a virtual environment? If you do - you will have to activate it first. For this go to the console and type

For windows:

```
activate vitual-environment-name
```

For ubuntu:

```
source activate virtual-environment-name
```

After that (and if you don't have a virtual environment) just type:

```
pip install -U matplotlib

If that doesn't work try:

python -m pip install -U matplotlib
```

---

But in your case the version of six should be >= 1.10.
To do that use pip again and in your console type

```
pip install -U six

If that doesn't work try:

python -m pip install -U six
```

Comment: Requirement already up-to-date: six in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (1.11.0)

Comment: Try to uninstall matplotlib and install it again (pip uninstall matplotlib --> pip install matplotlib)

Comment: the same problem, I don't understand what happen

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install -U matplotlib
```

it is easy to update modules